# Objective C, Core Data, NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, arrays, core-data

I have extracted data from a core data set and now would like to sum the values represented by Strings in the array. The following code works fine, but only picks up the first value encountered, how do I get it to loop and pick up the other values stored in the array?

```
if([rainResults count] == 0) {
    rainfallTotal = @"No rainfall recorded";
}

else {
    for (NSManagedObject *mo in rainResults) {
        rainfallAmount = [mo valueForKey:@"gauge"];
        rainSum = [rainfallAmount floatValue];
        NSString *intTotal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", rainSum];
        rainfallTotal = [intTotal stringByAppendingString:unitsString];
    }
}

UIAlertView *alertDialog;

alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rainfall" message:pickedGauge delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Total year to date", rainfallTotal, nil];

alertDialog.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;

[alertDialog show];
```

Comment: "Sum" meaning "add"? I don't see _any_ addition happening in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looping through OK, but doesn't look like you are actually summing the parsed values together?

ie. i would have thought your rainfall line would be something like this:

```
rainSum += [rainfallAmount floatValue];
```

Are you sure you are only seeing the FIRST value and not the LAST?

Comment: You are quite right, it is the LAST value, the addition of the "+" to make it rainSum += [rainfallAmount floatValue}; sadly did not fix the issue.

Comment: No problems. Glad I could help :-)